# Use Twitter API with Laravel AngularJS Satellizer

Tags: php, angularjs, laravel, twitter, satellizer

I've created an app with working log in to twitter via angularjs front end and Laravel back end and using the Satellizer library.

Now I want to interact with the Twitter Rest API, using the oAuth generated by satellizer, does anyone have a suggestion or library to do this? I've checked out thujohn/twitter Laravel plugin but I cant make it play nice with Satellizer and it doesnt cover all the api calls I want (search tweets, reply to tweets, get user timelines, get profiles)

All help appreciated!

Lewis

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone else in a similar situation: I found it easiest to just write my own functions rather than use a second lib.

Example route : 

`Route::post('tweet', ['middleware' => 'auth', 'uses' => 'TwitterController@tweet']);`

Example controller function: 

    `public function searchTweets(Request $request)
    {
      //
      $url = 'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json';
      $client = new GuzzleHttp\Client();
      $user = User::find($request['user']['sub']);
      $profileOauth = new Oauth1([
        'consumer_key' => Config::get('app.twitter_key'),
        'consumer_secret' => Config::get('app.twitter_secret'),
        'token' => $user->oauthToken,
        'token_secret' => $user->oauthVerifier
      ]);
      $client->getEmitter()->attach($profileOauth);
      $response = $client->get($url, ['auth' => 'oauth', 
                                      'query' => ['q' => $request->input('q'), 
                                                  'result_type' => $request->input('result_type'), 
                                                  #'since_id' => $request->input('since_id', 0), 
                                                  #'max_id' => $request->input('max_id', 0), 
                                                  'count' => $request->input('count')]
                                    ])->json();
      return $response;
    }`

And this is in my angularJS twitter factory: 

    `var vm = {};
    vm.tweets = [];
    vm.busy = false;
    vm.outreaches = 0;
    vm.retweets = 0;
    vm.favourites = 0;
    vm.followed = 0;
    vm.status = '';
    vm.since_id = null;
    vm.until = null;
    vm.max_id = null;
    vm.count = 100;
    vm.q = '';
    vm.result_type = 'mixed';
    /* 
     * mixed: Include both popular and real time results in the response.
     * recent: return only the most recent results in the response
     * popular: return only the most popular results in the response.
     */
    vm.searchTweets = function () {
      if (vm.busy) {
        return;
      }
      vm.busy = true;
      var url = "/twitter/search";
      $http({
        url: url,
        method: "GET",
        params: {
          q: vm.q,
          result_type: vm.result_type || 'mixed',
          count: vm.count || 100,
          since_id: vm.since_id || null,
          //until: vm.until || null,
          max_id: vm.max_id || null
        }
      }).then(function (response) {
        var newTweets = response.data.statuses;
        console.log('newTweets: ');
        console.log(newTweets);
        for (var i = 0; i < newTweets.length; i++) {
          vm.tweets.push(newTweets[i]);
        }
        vm.since_id = vm.tweets[vm.tweets.length - 1].id_str;
        vm.busy = false;
      }, function (response) {
        // called asynchronously if an error occurs
        // or server returns response with an error status.
        console.log(response);
        angular.forEach(response.data.errors, function(value, key){
          $window.Materialize.toast(value.message, 3000);
        });
      });
    };`